# How to fake a generic method call using FakeItEasy?

Tags: generics, dapper, fakeiteasy

I am faking an `IDbConnection` and I want to fake the call to `QueryOne<T>()` (a `Dapper`extension) but I get a `NullReferenceException` when doing so.

Here´s my code:

```
IDbConnection myConnection = A.Fake<IDbConnection>();


A.CallTo(() => myConnection.QueryOne<MyDto>(A<string>.Ignored,  <IDbConnection>.Ignored, A<IDbTransaction>.Ignored))
.Returns(new MyDto());
```

Isn't it possible to mock a generic method call in `FakeItEasy` or why am I getting the exception?

Thanks in advance...

Christian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Dapper uses extension methods to supply its functionality and since extension methods are just fancy static methods, I don't think you will be able to get this to work.  From what I've read (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742425/fake-captcha-from-commonlibnet-with-fakeiteasy-and-fluentvalidation)) FakeItEasy can't intercept a static method.

Comment: Indeed, extensions don't play well with unit tests. My advice, use an interface which mimics the dapper calls you make and program against those interfaces making your unit tests easier to write.